# Is there a Kentico Small Business Edition for purchase?

Tags: kentico

Is there a Kentico Small Business Edition for purchase?

https://www.kentico.com/download-demo/free-cms-for-asp-net/kentico_12_editions.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You should email sales@kentico.com and ask them. Since what is available to purchase starts at Base on their site, this small business one might be a free one under special conditions or no longer offered.

Answer (score 1):

The Kentico Small Business License was introduced in 2009 as something that is only available to Kentico partners.  This was following feedback from existing partners that smaller clients who did not need the full features of Kentico CMS.

It is still available as far as I am aware, but you would need to be a partner to get access to it.